# google-apps-script | TypeError for getEvents()

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a calendar called 'IMPORTANT!!' which when subbed into my code causes it not to work (there is no error, the function just does nothing).  I think this problem is caused by the !! characters at the end of the name, but I do not know what that problem is or how to fix it.  What should I do to avoid this problem?

```
function myFunction() {  
var year = 2019;
var month = 0;

var fromDate = new Date(year,month,1,0,0,0);
var toDate = new Date(year,month,28,0,0,0);



  var theCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('IMPORTANT!!')[0];
  var events = theCalendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate);


  for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++){
    var ev = events[i];
    ev.deleteEvent();
  }

}
```

How do I fix the error so my script will delete all of the events from the google calendar posted in 'def' in january of 2019.

Answer (score 0):

`getCalendarsByName()` returns `Calendar[]` which is an array. So if the calendar name of `def` is only one in your calendars, how about following modification?

#### From:

```
var theCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('def');
```

#### To:

```
var theCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('def')[0];
```

#### Note:

- If you have several calendars with same calendar name, I recommend to use the calendar ID.
- As a point, when the method name is seen, it is found that "Calendars" of "getCalendarsByName" is plural. By this, it might notice that several values will be returned.

#### Reference:

- [getCalendarsByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getcalendarsbynamename)

### Edit 1:

About your new question, if `events` has not elements, the for loop doesn't work.

I think that this might be the reason of your new issue. Please confirm about this.

When events can be retrieved by `theCalendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate)`. `eleteEvent()` in the for loop will work.

### Edit 2:

You can retrieve the calendar IDs and calendar names of all calendars using the following script.

#### Sample script:

```
var result = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars().map(function(e) {return {id: e.getId(), name: e.getName()}});
Logger.log(result);
```

#### Result:

```
[
  {
    "id": "### calendarId1 ###",
    "name": "### calendarName1 ###"
  },
  {
    "id": "### calendarId2 ###",
    "name": "### calendarName2 ###"
  },
  ,
  ,
  ,
]
```

Comment: yes that did it but now I am having another problem outlined above ^^

Comment: @brothman @brothman Thank you for replying. I'm surprised that your question is suddenly changed. At first, can I ask you about whether your initial question of ``I am getting an error for 'getEvents()' which is a function that I have used before.`` was resolved?

Comment: @brothman I updated my answer for your new question. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: thecalendar IMPORTANT!! has many events, is it possible the problem is coming form the "!!"?

Comment: @brothman No. I have confirmed that even when ``!!`` is added the calendar name, the script works fine.

Comment: hmm that is weird, because it does not work for me.  I think I renamed this calendar a long time ago so it may still be using that name... How do I get the name being used by the calendar in appscript if that name differs from the name displayed on the calendar)?

Comment: @brothman Although I'm not sure about your current situation, how about using the calendar ID?

Comment: yes, I think that will work.  How can I quickly get the IDs of every calendar?  Then when I have all of the ids, can I use 
```CalendarApp.getCalendarById(#)```?

Comment: @brothman I added a sample script for retrieving the calendar IDs and calendar names of all calendars. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @brothman Thank you for replying. If you have any issues for this situation, can I ask you about it?